# Why is the data written by imageStore for integer Sampler interpretted as Float?

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I have the following compute shader reading data from iimage2D and replacing the data based on its color value. The problem here I face is that though I read data in integer format and write back in integer the written data is interpreted as float value between 0 to 1. Hence getting unexpected output.

Following is the Compute shader:

```
layout(rgba32i) coherent uniform iimage2D i_image2D;

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;
void main() 
{
ivec2 idx = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
ivec4 readTexel = imageLoad(i_image2D, idx);
if(readTexel[0] == 0 && readTexel[1] == 2147483647 && readTexel[2] == 0 &&       readTexel[3] == 2147483647)
{ 
    readTexel = ivec4(2147483647,0,0,2147483647);
}
else
{
    readTexel = ivec4(0,2147483647,0,2147483647); 
}

imageStore(i_image2D, idx, readTexel);
```

}

Comment: Where are you determining how the data is interpreted? Do you have another shader you are not showing? I think what is probably happening is you have not setup a memory barrier and what you are actually experiencing are the results of data hazards. The `coherent` qualifier does not guarantee anything about the order of invocations, and this shader looks pretty order-dependent to me.

Comment: I am not using any other shader for accessing this and I determine the result by its output drawn. The geometry must have a light shade of RED or GREEN, but it draws a full alpha colors. Is it that we need to normalize the color as done in fragment shader. Normalizing integer to Float values?

Comment: This shader does not output any color. Which is why I asked, do you have a shader where you actually draw using an integer texture based on the image you loaded/stored?